# Target specific product category and it's children in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to add custom content before shop content but only when viewing products in specific category with this category childs.

Thoes categories are: main category - *'events'*, child categories - *'seminarium'*, *'course'* and *'training'*.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'eventsTerms', 18);
function eventsTerms() {

  $term = get_term_by('name', 'events', 'product_cat');
  $term_id = $term->term_id;
  $taxonomyName = 'product_cat';
  $termChildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomyName );

foreach ( $termChildren as $child ) {
  $_term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
  $childTerms= ', "' . '' . $_term->name . '"';

  echo $childTerms; // only to see is ok

}

    if ( is_product_category( array("events", $childTerms) ) ) {
    global $product;
    wp_list_categories( 
      array(
          'show_option_all' => 'show all',
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'style' => 'none',
          'separator' => '',
          'hide_empty' => 0,
      ));

  }

}
```

`$childTerms` returns all child categories names, so I want to use `is_product_category` conditional tag with array, but my code still works only on main category "events".

Where's the bug?

**EDIT 1**

Ok, I thought the reason why it's not working is `implode` can't be using in `is_product_category()` args. So I was trying with `json_encode` like that:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'eventsTerms', 18);
function eventsTerms() {

  $term = get_term_by('name', 'events', 'product_cat');
  $term_id = $term->term_id;
  $taxonomyName = 'product_cat';
  $termChildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomyName );

foreach ( $termChildren as $child ) {
  $_term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
  $childTerms[] = " '".$_term->name."'";
}

$x = implode(",", $childTerms);

$y = json_encode($x);

echo $y; // output as " 'seminarium', 'course', 'training'"

$y2 = preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":/','$1:', $x); // removing qutes by preg_replace

echo $y2; // output as 'seminarium', 'course', 'training'

    if ( is_product_category( array('events', $y) ) ) {
    global $product;
    wp_list_categories( 
      array(
          'show_option_all' => 0,
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'style' => 'none',
          'separator' => '',
          'hide_empty' => 0,
          'child_of' => $term_id,
      ));

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) doesn't work with `"id"`, **but with `"term_id"` instead** *(or `"slug"` or `"name"`)*. 
The function [`get_term_children()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/) gives an array of **Terms IDs**. 
The conditional function [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-is_product_category.html#50-58) accepts an array of term names, slugs or Ids, as it's based on [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) function.

You are making things more complicated than they should be and you don't need a foreach loop.

#### To target a specific product category and its related children:

**1) On Archive pages:**

```
$term_slug = 'events';
$taxonomy  = 'product_cat';

$term_id   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id; // Get the term ID
$child_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get the children terms IDs
$terms_ids = array_merge( $child_ids, array($term_id) ); // an array of all term IDs (main term Id and it's children)

if ( is_product_category( $terms_ids ) ) {
    // Do something
}
```

So in you code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'eventsTerms', 18 );
function eventsTerms() {
    $term_slug = 'events';
    $taxonomy  = 'product_cat';

    $term_id   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id; // Get the term ID
    $child_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get the children terms IDs
    $terms_ids = array_merge( $child_ids, array($term_id) ); // an array of all term IDs (main term Id and it's children)

    if ( is_product_category( $terms_ids ) ) {
        global $product;
        
        wp_list_categories( array(
            'show_option_all' => 'show all',
            'taxonomy'        => 'product_cat',
            'style'           => 'none',
            'separator'       => '',
            'hide_empty'      => 0,
            'child_of'        => $term_id,
        ) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active active theme).* Tested and works.

---

**2) On product pages, cart items or order items** *(instead of archive pages)*:

You will use conditional function [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/), that accepts also an array of term names, slugs or Ids *(The third argument (optional) is the post ID or the product ID for WooCommerce products)*:

```
$term_slug = 'events';
$taxonomy  = 'product_cat';

$term_id   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id; // Get the term ID
$child_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get the children terms IDs
$terms_ids = array_merge( $child_ids, [$term_id] ); // an array of all term IDs (main term Id and it's children)

if ( has_term( $terms_ids, $taxonomy, $product_id ) ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see there is `is_product_category( $terms_ids )' in your code, but it seems to me that conditional tag may contain only slugs, not IDs. Unfortunately this code doesn't work :(

Comment: And works for child terms too? In my case works only for the parent category :/

Comment: Ok, I agree, in $terms_ids there is array of child terms. But it does not change the fact that this script works only on parent category, I mean on "product-category/events/", but for eg. on "product-category/events/courses" does not.

Comment: Thanks to answer on other group I get the final working code. Instead of $terms_ids = [$term_id] + $child_ids; I use $terms_ids = array_merge( $child_ids, [$term_id] ); and now works like I want to!

Comment: in case of multiple main category how to do this?